# Getting another Java Program's Sound

Tags: java, audio, javasound, recording

I'm writing a video recording program, and it's going quite well. I can record mic as well as video from the screen. However, I would also like to be able to obtain sounds from another Java program and then sync them with the video. Basically, record the audio as it is played by the other program.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm pretty new with sound, and have read a bit up on it. I think I need to set up a mixer, but I'm not sure if I can actually obtain sound from another Java program that way.

Comment: Java's sound API is pretty lacking, sadly.

Comment: Yeah, I did notice that. Is there any way at all I could get this to work, even using an external API?

Comment: Is the "other" Java program one that you can reprogram? Does this other program allow you to specify a mixer? I'm also wondering about setting the Java audio program to send a bytestream to your recorder rather than audio. Or even, setting up your recorder to have a second interface that does the audio playback for mixing. That would likely have the best performance. (I am totally brainstorming here, I really haven't done much with obtaining lines using TargetDataLine.)

Comment: Nor have I, really. I don't know much about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with java sound, not because of any particular problem with java sound, but because not all audio APIs that java builds on support this feature. (Core audio on the mac for example, and ASIO on windows. Not sure about ALSA on linux, but I don't think it supports this either).

If you are on windows and want to write JNI/JNA code you can use PortAudio which supports this on one of the audio APIs (sorry I can't recall which one).

Comment: Would ffmpeg be able to do this? Or would it not work at all?

Comment: I don't believe so. FFMPEG would have the same problem as Java: the feature has to be made available by the underlying audio API.

Comment: Ah. So is it just not possible then I assume without using JNI / JNA?

Comment: The issue is: can the platform you are running on do it? Some can, some can't. If it can, then you need to come up with some way to do what you want, which might be JNI/JNA, but depending on your needs, you might be able to launch a separate process to do whatever it is you want.

Comment: I'm currently using windows, and the main users of this program will be windows.

Comment: You can use PortAudio. http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/java_binding.html has java bindings for portaudio. I believe Portaudio's WMME or WASAPI supports the features you want (I can't recall exactly, you may need to ask on the mailing list or dig around on the site to figure out which API will work), but only in the very limited case that the app you are recording is running on that same audio API. You may also need to modify the java bindings to support this feature.